# Is there a way to tell which application last accessed your camera?

Tags: security, camera

Is there an application which will tell me which programs have last accessed my camera?

Comment: I'd like to know too... like a hardware accessed log?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on watching `/dev/video*` using `inotifywait`. Start by installing *inotify-tools*:

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

Then insert the following line into the file `/etc/rc.local`, **before** the line with `exit 0`:

```
/usr/bin/inotifywait --timefmt "%F %T" --format "%T %w %e" --daemon --outfile /var/log/camera.log /dev/video*
```

Reboot. The accesses to any `/dev/video*` device will be logged to `/var/log/camera.log`.